# Automatically download Dropbox Favorites to the external SD card

Tags: dropbox

When a file is marked as *favorite* on the Dropbox app it is downloaded to the phone's internal memory for offline viewing. Dropbox also "attempts to keep the file as up-to-date as possible and gives you the option to update the file manually". [[source]](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/87)

My question is - Is there a way to have Dropbox download the favorite files to an external SD card? I am aware of the "export" option, which allows you to save files to the external SD card, but it is cumbersome and does not keep the downloaded files up to date.

Any ideas?